# How can I print colored debug messages with Flutter / Dart to show colored Android Studio console output?

Tags: android, debugging, flutter, dart

How can I print colored debug messages with Flutter/Dart to show colored Android Studio console/logcat output?
There are many dart packages that provide the escape characters for colored output but the Android Studio simply does not show them.

Some of them are: https://github.com/iamsalnikov/colorize or https://pub.dev/packages/ansicolor

Or simply some escape characters should work as well:

```
   print('\x1B[94m $text \x1B[0m');
```

These messages show up like this:

```
 [94m [36m57 2019-10-18 16:18:55.694098 FINE ui.app.dart: initial route = null[0m [0m
```

My question is, can I exchange the console to see the escape characters? 
Or just any other way?

Comment: what OS? my android studio on linux shows colors with no problems

Comment: Windows 10. The console is the on inside Android Studio.

Comment: that console  (ALT + F12)? or something else?

Comment: The debug output console. I am not add my computer right now.

Comment: Also logcat does not show the coloring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible at this point. How this works exactly is still a bit unclear to me but it hinges on the [supportsAnsiEscapes](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/Stdout/supportsAnsiEscapes.html) method. This outputs `false` when running in Android Studio:

```dart
import 'dart:io' as io;
print(io.stdout.supportsAnsiEscapes);
```

Escape sequences are then simply ignored.

Note that even if this call would return true Android Studio only supports a limited subset of ANSI colors: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137065

Comment: Seems like the defect is around for the last 5 years

Comment: It does not inspire confidence.